# Getting wrong values returned from cl::BufferGL after a upgrade from HD6790 to HD7850

Tags: opencl, gpu, amd-processor

I can write data to cl::BufferGL variables (on GPU) and use it to draw, but I got wrong values when reading back to host. I have ran a couple examples from AMD SDK, including GL_CL interop, and is all ok. I can read and write cl::Buffer, i.e., copy from host to device and copy from device to host.

The source code is hosted at [link](https://github.com/lucasribeiroufrj/sph-project).

To create the cl::Buffer I do steps below (in order, and after get a cl_gl context):

1. glGenBuffer
2. glBindBuffer
3. glBufferData
4. clCreateFromGLBuffer
5. glBindBuffer (bind to 0, or unbind)

The program is written using:

- C++
- Ubuntu 12.06 64 bits, kernel 3.2.0-29-generic
- OpenCL 1.2
- Driver 1124.2 (Binary driver from AMD, Catalyst 13.4)
- AMD APPSDK v2.8
- OpenGL Version: 4.2.12217
- Glew
- Freeglut

EDIT: I've created a code block to reproduce the error

```
// Terminates OpenCL commands
cl_int status = 0;
status =  clFinish( (cq)() );
if ( status != CL_SUCCESS ) { printf("File: %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);  }

// Create Vertex buffer object
GLint  number = 5;
GLuint buffer;
CHk_ERR( glGenBuffers( 1, &buffer ));
CHk_ERR( glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer ) );

// initialize buffer object
GLsizeiptr     size = static_cast<GLsizeiptr>(sizeof(number));
const GLvoid * data = static_cast<const GLvoid *>(&number);
CHk_ERR( glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) );
CHk_ERR( glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) );
glFinish();

if ( glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR ) { printf("File: %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);  }

// create OpenCL buffer from GL VBO
cl_mem mem = clCreateFromGLBuffer( (context)(), CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, buffer, &status );
if ( status != CL_SUCCESS ) { printf("File: %s:%d\n", __FILE__, __LINE__);  }

// Acquire OpenCL memory objects that have been created from OpenGL objects
if ( clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects( (cq)(), 1, &(mem), 0, NULL, NULL ) != CL_SUCCESS ){
    std::cout << "ERROR!";
}

// Read buffer
GLint value;
cq.enqueueReadBuffer( mem, CL_TRUE, 0, size, &value );
std::cout << "Value: " << value << std::endl;
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: You will have to post some details about your application, and probably some host/kernel code before anyone will be able to help you out.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Which kind of details? My program is very big, object oriented, and I guess paste code would be a problem.

Comment: Hard to guess without code details. My guess is you are missing clFinish after clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects or glFinish before clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects, per the OpenCL specification (perhaps section 9.7 but that's from memory)

Comment: Very weird, the code does not return any error. And I am doing the sequence glFinish(); clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects(...); enqueueReadBuffer(...);

Comment: I've added a git rep with the hole project at [link](https://github.com/lucasribeiroufrj/sph-project), if you can, please take a look.

Comment: Dithermaster is right. New series have some concurrency things so putting a clFinish before a gl and then putting a glFinish before the cl fixes mostly if implicit sync is not enough.

Comment: I've done the suggestion, but nothing changed. Do you have any other ideia?